# Convert Hex to Decimal Value

Tags: java

If I have a hex value of 53, what is the best way in Java to see what the values of bit 6 and bit 7 are?  Bit 1 will be considered as the Least Significant Bit (or the rightmost bit within a byte).

The goal is to take bit6 and bit7 and convert them to its combined decimal form.

Comment: You can mask each bit with the corresponding power of 2 number. For example, to know the value of the fourth bit you would use bitwise and with 8. x & 8 => x & (2^3)

Comment: The usual bit addressing is that the least significant bit is bit 0, not bit 1.

Comment: While not a direct answer to your question, you may also be interested in [Integer.toBinaryString(int)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#toBinaryString(int))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is easy:

```
byte b = 53;
boolean bit6 = ((b >> 5) & 1) == 1;
boolean bit7 = ((b >> 6) & 1) == 1;
```

Or:

```
byte b = 53;
int bit6and7 = b & (0x3 << 5); // Will give: 0 bit7 bit6 0 0 0 0 0
```

Or:

```
byte b = 53;
int bit6and7 = (b >> 5) & 0x3; // Will give: 0 0 0 0 0 0 bit7 bit6
```

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way, I think is:

```
int bits7And8 = (byteValue >>> 5) & 3;
```

That will give you bits 6 and 7 in the lowest two bit positions. If you need their value as a `String`:

```
String bits7And8String = Integer.toString(bits7And8);
```

Comment: @c12 - Sorry - I was off by one because of your unconventional indexing of the least significant bit being 1 instead of 0.

Comment: byte byteValue = 53;  is that what you intended for your example?  assuming a hex of 53.

Comment: @c12 - If the hex value is 53 (binary 01010011), then bits 7 and 8 (6 and 7 in your indexing scheme) are binary 10, which is 2 in decimal. That's what I understood you to want. (The "`7And8`" in the variable names should be "`6And7`" to be consistent with your indexing scheme.)